# ADOQuery2: Parameter 'Otdelenie1' not found. Синтаксис SQL в Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-server, delphi-xe

Delphi жалуется, что не нашел параметра, хотя он есть. Что тут может быть не так?

```
    ADOQuery2.SQL.Clear;
    ADOQuery2.SQL.Text :=
    'UPDATE STUDENTALL'+
    'SET Otdelenie=:Otdelenie1'+
    'where Familiya=:Familiya and Imya=:Imya  and Otchestvo=:Otchestvo and Period=:Period';
     ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Familiya').Value := FamiliyaQ;
     ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Imya').Value := ImyaQ;
     ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Otchestvo').Value := OtchestvoQ;
     ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Otdelenie1').Value := OtdelenieQ;
     ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Period').Value := Period.items[Period.ItemIndex];
     ADOQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Вопрос вызван опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Стоит его удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Все нашла ошибку, дело не в синтаксисе, просто в строке запроса не было пробела после параметра, всем спасибо.